# React native look if another view key exists , or if another component of same key exists

Tags: react-native

```
renderRow(items)
  {
    return items.map((item) => { 
      return (<View style={styles.column} key={"row"+item.id}>
                <View style={styles.fixCellWidth}><Text>{item.species}</Text></View>
            </View>)
   });
  }
```

I want to check if my view key exists then it will not display same items again.

Like in jQuery we check the length of some id of div, For example we have div with id =1 and we dont want to display it again so we can search that div with id = 1 exists then it will not display again. so we use if($(".box").length>1){}else{}, same type of searching i want in react native. i m new please help me to find that the  exists once then it wil not display again.

```
     <div id="1" class="box">Sam</div> <div id="2" box">Roy</div>
```

Comment: It seems to me you are doing something wrong. If you have array of unique items you do not have to take care if something will be rerendered.
You can check directly in items if item exists. Also this is not dom, if you do not render something it will be removed from layout.